# Line drawing animation left, down, lef with pure css

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm using css transition to drawing a line, it run or loading from right to left, and then down, and continue to load to left:

```
point 1------point 2 
               |
               |
               |
               ---------point 3
```

this is my css:

```css
  .transitionLine {
    height:0px;
    width:1px;
    border:10px solid #ef4e4e;
    
    -webkit-animation: increase 3s;
    -moz-animation:    increase 3s; 
    -o-animation:      increase 3s; 
    animation:         increase 3s; 
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  @keyframes increase {
   /*load to left*/
   30% {    
    width: 500px;
   }
   /*load down*/
   60% {
    border-radius: 3px;    
    width: 1000px;
   }
   /*load to left*/
   100% {
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 1500px;
   }
  }
```

```html
<div class="transitionLine"></div>
```

my css seem not break line to load down and left, how to fix the problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible with just one line / div. Or at least not possible when just working with animating the width only. To do this with pure css I'd say you either need more lines, or maybe you could use `clip-path`'s polygon mode if you don't care about browser support.

Comment: I think with my case can use more line or div, but my problem is how to combine lines to load transition together when load down and left..

Comment: @KhauriMcClain see Nidhi's answer it possible with css

Comment: @לבנימלכה Ah yes I see. Clever use of the `after` pseudo element.

Comment: Is it just me who finds it confusing to read right to left everywhere and see the line go from left to right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this effect as per my snippet.

I have used `Two keyframes` and an `after` property to add bottom line

```css
.transitionLine {
    height: 0px;
    width: 1px;
    border-top: 10px solid #ef4e4e;
    border-right: 10px solid #ef4e4e;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: increase 3s;
    -moz-animation: increase 3s;
    -o-animation: increase 3s;
    animation: increase 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

.transitionLine:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 0px;
    width: 1px;
    border-top: 10px solid #ef4e4e;
    border-right: 10px solid #ef4e4e;
    -webkit-animation: increase2 3s;
    -moz-animation: increase2 3s;
    -o-animation: increase2 3s;
    animation: increase2 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}

@keyframes increase {

    /*load to left*/
    30% {
        width: 200px;
        height: 0px;
    }

    31% {
        width: 200px;
        height: 1px;
    }

    /*load down*/
    60% {
        height: 100px;
        width: 200px;
    }

    /*load to left*/
    100% {
        height: 100px;
        width: 200px;
    }
}

@keyframes increase2 {
    60% {
        height: 0px;
        width: 0px;
    }

    /*load to left*/
    100% {
        height: 0px;
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="transitionLine"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use gradient to draw lines and you will need only one keyframe:

```css
.transitionLine {
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  background-image:
   linear-gradient(#ef4e4e,#ef4e4e),
   linear-gradient(#ef4e4e,#ef4e4e),
   linear-gradient(#ef4e4e,#ef4e4e);
  background-size:
    0% 5px,
    5px 0%,
    0% 5px;
  background-position:
    top left,
    top center,
    150px 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  animation: increase 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes increase {
  30% {
    background-size:
    50% 5px,
    5px 0%,
    0% 5px;
  }
  /*load down*/
  60% {
    background-size:
    50% 5px,
    5px 100%,
    0% 5px;
  }
  /*load to left*/
  100% {
    background-size:
    50% 5px,
    5px 100%,
    50% 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="transitionLine"></div>
```

That you can easily scale to any number of lines:

```css
.transitionLine {
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  background-image:
   linear-gradient(#ef4e4e,#ef4e4e),
   linear-gradient(#ef4e4e,#ef4e4e),
   linear-gradient(#ef4e4e,#ef4e4e),
   linear-gradient(#ef4e4e,#ef4e4e),
   linear-gradient(#ef4e4e,#ef4e4e);
  background-size:
    5px 0%,
    0% 5px,
    5px 0%,
    0% 5px,
    5px 0%;
  background-position:
    bottom left,
    top left,
    top center,
    150px 100%,
    right bottom;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  animation: increase 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes increase {
  20% {
    background-size:
    5px 100%,
    0% 5px,
    5px 0%,
    0% 5px,
    5px 0%;
  }
  40% {
    background-size:
    5px 100%,
    50% 5px,
    5px 0%,
    0% 5px,
    5px 0%;
  }
  60% {
    background-size:
    5px 100%,
    50% 5px,
    5px 100%,
    0% 5px,
    5px 0%;
  }
  80% {
    background-size:
    5px 100%,
    50% 5px,
    5px 100%,
    50% 5px,
    5px 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-size:
    5px 100%,
    50% 5px,
    5px 100%,
    50% 5px,
    5px 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="transitionLine"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.transitionLine {
    height:0px;
    width:1px;
    border:10px solid #ef4e4e;
    -webkit-animation: increase 1s;
    -moz-animation:    increase 1s; 
    -o-animation:      increase 1s; 
    animation:         increase 1s; 
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.transitionLine:before{
    height: 0px;
    content: " ";
    width: 0px;
    border: 10px solid #ef4e4e;
    -webkit-animation: increaseA 1s;
    -moz-animation: increaseA 1s;
    -o-animation: increaseA 1s;
    animation: increaseA 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    margin: -10px 0 0 510px;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
}
.transitionLine:after{
    height: 0px;
    content: " ";
    width: 0px;
    border: 10px solid #ef4e4e;
    -webkit-animation: increaseB 1s;
    -moz-animation: increaseB 1s;
    -o-animation: increaseB 1s;
    animation: increaseB 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    margin: 0px 0 0 510px;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes increase {
    0% {       
        width: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        width: 500px;
    } 
}
@keyframes increaseA {
    0% {       
        height: 0px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        height: 500px;
        opacity: 1;
    } 
}
@keyframes increaseB {
    0% {       
        width: 0px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        width: 500px;
        opacity: 1;
    } 
}





<div class="transitionLine"></div>
```